# Abstract fixed hierarchy of objects and Type "pollution"

Tags: c#, generics, hierarchy, abstract

I have a fixed hierarchy of abstract objects. I am making the classes generic so each node in the tree is aware of it's children. By doing this, I am finding that each parent in the tree gets crazier every time a new node is added:

```
public abstract class AbstractChoiceTree<SectionType,
                                            LevelType,
                                            CueType,
                                            SectorType,
                                            PhaseType,
                                            ChargeType> : AbstractModel
        where SectionType : AbstractSection<CueType, SectorType, PhaseType, ChargeType>
        where LevelType : AbstractLevel<SectorType, PhaseType>
        where CueType : AbstractCue<ChargeType>
        where SectorType : AbstractSector
        where PhaseType : AbstractPhase
        where ChargeType : AbstractCharge
{
}
```

I feel like I am doing something VERY wrong here. Is there a saner approach to this?

Thanks

Comment: It's not very common to actually need the object to be aware of its children's types in so much detail. Maybe you should just be using, e.g. `AbstractSection` directly instead of `SectionType`.

Comment: You're not gonna need it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it

Comment: Can you add more context into what you're trying to do with these types? Why do they need to be aware of their children? I would try to navigate toward a design where the parents are not aware of their children's types. Alternatively, this knowledge can be expressed in state rather than in static type (i.e. in actual fields rather than the generic type arguments).